# laravel: protecting against query that comes back null

Tags: php, laravel

I had a query that checks the User table for a user who has a specific code and grabs that user , and sets it to $mainCustomer.  I just realized there are situations where there might not be a User with that code.  I thought my check underneath that for `! $mainCustomer` would cover me but I believe I might get an error with the query itself if it's null.  How can I protect against an error with the query?

```
        $mainCustomer = User::where('code', '=', $value_code)->first();

        if (! $mainCustomer) {
            log_info("doesn't exist");

            return;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the query itself if it's null"? Your code's gonna work fine, but you might consider using `firstOrFail()` to simplify things.

Comment: Are you getting $value_code from Request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return User::where('code', '=', $value_code)->firstOrFail();`

The method will retrieve the first result of the query; however, if no result is found, a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` will be thrown:
If the exception is not caught, a 404 HTTP response is automatically sent back to the user. It is not necessary to write explicit checks to return 404 responses when using these methods.

Is this what you are after?

Comment: thanks @Andy !  I don;'t have to `return` though when using it, right?  Can I just replace `first()` in my example with `firstOrFail()` and then use the `! $mainCustomer` below to check so I can still log the info?

Comment: i think you are looking for firstOr() https://twitter.com/calebporzio/status/999004306312499205

Comment: @burtonLowel if that's all what you want, then your code should be fine, are you facing some errors with your code?

Comment: no, I was just told by another engineer that using `->first()` can result in an error if a database record doesn't exist

Comment: your `if` check already handles that, if there is no record the method ends